# recursive lambda implemention in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I interested to recursive lambda implementation, and found this code for Fibonacci calculation:

```
 std::function<int(int)> lfib = [&lfib](int n) {return n < 2 ? 1 : lfib(n-1) + lfib(n-2);};
```

And I have a question: `std::function` is a polymorphic function, so `lfib` creates/and saves the lambda in heap memory, not on the stack. And therefore **may lose optimization possibilities** of the program. Correct or not?

Comment: To a program with O(2^N) algorithmic complexity, the mechanics of the function call don't matter.

Comment: I wasn't ask about implementation fibbonachi, I was asked about std::function may loss optimization the program.

Comment: In practice, yes. But why would you ever do this? You only get an additional layer of abstraction and that's just not necessary. There's hardly ever the need for recursive lambda (which this actually isn't. this is just a lambda that calls a `std::function`).

Comment: I will convert this json d library to C++:
https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/json.d

Answer (score 5):

The type-erasure data which is the state of `std::function` will persist as long as the `std::function` or its copies live, probably via heap allocation.

The same is not true of the closure, which contains captured variables.  That's part of the state of the lambda object, and probably contains the address of a data structure on the stack, which will disappear when the current function returns and the variable `lfib` goes out of scope.

Remember that you've captured `lfib` by reference.  Therefore any changes to `lfib` for the remainder of the function have to be visible to the lambda (including but not limited to the initialization).  The only way the compiler can manage that in a general way is by storing the address of the local `lfib`.  In your particular case, if `lfib` is not assigned again, it might be possible for the compiler to store the value immediately post-initialization instead of a reference.  But it's not guaranteed, and not even particularly likely.

Comment: Such a small lambda will likely end up in the Small Buffer Optimization and not cause any heap-alloc.

Comment: @Xeo: Quite possibly.  I'm not an expert in `std::function` implementations.  What's of interest here is the lifetime.

Comment: @Xeo: not in libstdc++, where lambdas, for some reason, are never stored directly in `std::function` itself, because they're not considered "location-invariant". See `std::_Function_base::_Base_manager::__stored_locally`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but stored locally allowed only for pointer to function or pointer to member functions. For all other states don't stored locally.